# Question about showing that $f$ is a split monomorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

For the following question (taken from Arbib and Manes' *Arrows, structures and functors* text):

> **Question.**  Prove that $f \colon A\rightarrow B$ is one-to-one then $f$ is a split monomorphism, i.e., that there exist $g \colon B\rightarrow A$ with $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$.

What I would like to know is, the function $g$ requested in the exercise, is it that since $f$ is one-to-one, then for each $a \in A$, there exist exactly one $b \in f(A)$ where $g(b) = a_b$ if $b \in f(A) \subset B$, else $g(b) = a$ for $B \setminus f(A) \subset B$. Hence, for each $x \in A$ we have $(g \circ f)(a) = g(f(a)) = g(b) = a_{f(x)}$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141172/discussion-on-question-by-seth-question-about-showing-that-f-is-a-split-monomo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us suppose that $f:A\to B$ is an injective function with non-empty domain. The following is an explicit, detailed description of how to construct the function you want:

> For every element $b$ of the image $f(A)$ there exists, simply because it is in that image, an element $a_b$ in $A$ such that $f(a_b)=b$, and since the function $f$ is injective, there is, in fact, exactly one such element.

> On the other hand, since the set $A$ is not empty, we can pick an element $\alpha$ in A$.

> Using these two facts we can define a function $g:B\to A$: for each $b\in B$ we let $$g(b)=\begin{cases}a_b & \text{if $b$ belongs to the image $f(A)$;}\\ \alpha & \text{if it does not.}\end{cases}$$

Can you now check that $f\circ g$ is the identity map of $A$?

Comment: yes I can see how $(g\circ f)(b)$ is the identity many of $A$ in both cases.  Thank you so very much for taking the effort to point out my mistakes.  I really appreciate it.